# Mathematically finding the bounds of a CDF for a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to solve this question that asks for the pdf of a new variable V such that V = X*Y. The given information is $\begin{align*}
f(x,y)&=\frac{2x+y}{36}           &  0 \leq y \leq x, \hspace{5mm} x + 2y \leq 6            \\
\end{align*}$
.
My Issue is I can't figure out the bounds/cases for the new variable V, algebraically. When using desmos to graph the bounds and cases, I can clearly see that the cases are $0 \leq v \leq 4$ and $4 \leq v \leq 4.5$. However I am struggling to find these bounds without the use of a graphing aid. My method of solving is to find the CDF of each bound and then take the derivative of each component to find the pdf.

Comment: Question: What is $f$?

Comment: If you are referring to f(x,y), that represents the joint probability distribution for the random variables x and y.

Answer (score 1):

First we figure out for which $(x,y)$ the above pdf takes nonzero values. Notice that $0 \leq x,y$ by the first inequality and that $x \leq 6$ and $y \leq 3$ by the second. Therefore, for any given value of $x \in [0,6]$, the density is nonzero precisely for $y \in [0, \min(x, 3 - \frac{x}{2})]$. Now let us look at the cdf of $V$. Clearly $0 \leq V$ so that it is enough to consider $v \geq 0$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(V \leq v) &= \mathbb{P}(XY \leq v)\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)\, \mathbb{I}(xy \leq v)\, dy \,dx \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{2x + y}{36} \mathbb{I}(0 \leq y \leq x,\, x + 2y \leq 6,\, xy \leq v)\, dy\,dx \\
&= \int_0^6 \int_0^{\min(3 - \frac{x}{2}, x, \frac{v}{x})} \frac{2x+y}{36} dy\,dx.
\end{align}
Now you can try to look at the $3$ possible cases. We have
\begin{align}
x \leq 3 - \frac{x}{2} \quad&\iff\quad x \leq 2 \\
x \leq \frac{v}{x} \quad&\iff\quad x^2 \leq v \\
\frac{v}{x} \leq 3 - \frac{x}{2} \quad&\iff\quad x \not\in [3 - \sqrt{9-2v}, 3 + \sqrt{9-2v}].
\end{align}
From the above you start seeing the different behaviour depending on the value of $v$ that you observed graphically. For example: if $v > 4.5$ then $\frac{v}{x} > 3 - \frac{x}{2}$ for every $x$.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't really answer my question. I am still confused on how to find the numerical bounds mathematically?

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully answer your question better.